# How to close pop up window in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, popup

Can't close pop up window which appears right after http://www.cargo.lt/ loads. Here's what I've got:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.cargo.lt/asp/index.asp?')
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[36]/div/a').click()
```

I'm not very familiar with how to write custom xpath/css path and now just clicked on Inspect element and copied xpath. What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
What a stupid mistake. Didn't realize that when element is off screen Selenium can't click on it. Just added driver.maximize_window() and all my problems are gone. Thanks all for your answers. Unfortunately I can't vote yet, because I don't have enough points...

Answer (score 2):

hi to close pop up /alert please use

```
driver.switch_to_alert()
```

then use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[36]/div/a').click()
```

// if u have copied pasted form firebug then it will be correct i guess

or if ur xpath is not correct then use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='advert_x']").click()
```

Answer (score 2):

i tried your code it's work fine i don't know whats you problem but
try this : `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`
insted of :

```
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Implicit waits are very slow and should be avoided at all costs. When you add an implicit wait you are basically saying: "Wait X amount of seconds before executing each action".
If you need a page to load and it isn't fast enough you should find an element on this page that is only on the page once it is loaded. You can then use WebDriverWait to wait till this element is present and thus the page is loaded. If not use time.sleep() if it's a one time wait.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Predefined commands in python -Selenium to switch to alert box.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.cargo.lt/asp/index.asp?')
alrt = driver.switch_to_alert()
alrt.accept()
```

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use chrome options

in Python, you can use

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
webdriver.Chrome(os.path.join(path, 'chromedriver'),chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

in java

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("test-type");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```