# How to use selenium and Python to click 'accept cookies' button in popup, how can I move on when popup has no x

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, popup, popupwindow

I am new to using the selenium module. I have started with some simple tutorials which go ok until I get a popup.

Because the popup does not have an x, I am not able to apply other advice I have found online.
[How to close pop up window in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980373/how-to-close-pop-up-window-in-selenium)

However I have tried to inspect the code of the popup window and I can see that maybe I have a couple of options, close by referencing the link text 'Accept Cookies', or close by the button id which is "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"

[image]

This is the code I have so far.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/senior-insight-analyst/42347955")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
link.click()
```

Trying

**link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")**

and

**link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Accept cookies")**

Result in errors

*NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"onetrust-accept-btn-handler"}*

or

*NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Accept cookies"}*

I am wondering if there is any better command than link text if the button id is known, or am I missing another step in the process because it is a pop up? Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Its not link text, Its clearly button tag with id, so why dont you try with `driver.find_element_by _xpath("//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")`?

Comment: Thank you Dev. This advice I believe has moved it on a step I think. I have now got a different error to research from performing this action. I now get WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable. I'll try and research.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the **explicit wait** so that your popup window can come up and your selenium script can detect the element and click on it.

Use the below code -

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()
```

Mark it as answer if it resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Swaroop Humane and Dev for your answers. The answer above works, I also needed to add in three more lines of import code before the solution managed to click the Accept cookies button in the pop up. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Final code below.

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/senior-insight-analyst/42347955")

#driver.implicitly_wait(10)
#link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
#link.click()


WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()
```

Then this happened.

[image]

I probably need to figure out a way to run selenium while I am signed into this webservice, rather than let it run a new browser every time. Any ideas?